# Laravel 4 in a subfolder

Tags: html, web, laravel

I have a test project on Laravel 4, and I'm still new to this. I'm still working on wamp (localhost). I have already made it work as long as laravel is installed on the root path of wamp (..wamp/www), but when I try to create another folder (..wamp/www/testproject) and install laravel there, the routes are not working anymore except for localhost/testproject/laravel/public.

to summarize:

```
--The working one---
C:/wamp/www/laravel               = the folder where laravel was installed
localhost/laravel/public          = working, "You have arrived" page
localhost/laravel/about           = working about.php route

--The one with errors--
C:/wamp/www/testproject/laravel        = the folder where laravel was installed
localhost/testproject/laravel/public   = working, "You have arrived" page
localhost/testproject/laravel/about    = not working about.php route
localhost/testproject/laravel/index.php/about = working, and I don;t know why
```

can someone help me with this? why is it that the "about.php" page is not working on the subfolder? :(

EDIT: .htaccess file content

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

here is the screenshot for the routes..
[image: routes]

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file somewhere in your root folder or /public/ folder?

Comment: yes, both from the one with errors and the working one.. what to do about that?

Comment: What is the content of the .htaccess?

Comment: Hmm.. can you do a printout of your routes as well? `php artisan routes` on your Laravel installation in your subfolder

Comment: I would suggest create a VirtualHost on your machine so it will solve your problem as you will set Root directory - your subfolder...

Comment: I have added a printout sir Jofry...
I don't know yet how those things work, but I'll try doing it sir Dusan

Comment: Have you tried localhost/testproject/laravel/public/about

Comment: yes, it returns "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Answer (score -1):

Add `RewriteBase /laravel/public` below `RewriteEngine On` in `.htaccess`